# Inequality involving the tangent function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, fractions, substitution

How can one show that
$$x \tan x > \frac{4x - \pi}{\pi - 2x},$$
for $x \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Clearly, for $x \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ as $4x - \pi < 0$ and $\pi - 2x > 0$ the term $\frac{4x - \pi}{\pi - 2x}$ is negative while $x \tan x$ is always positive, so one need only show the inequality is true for $x \in \left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: I am sure this inequality will involve calculus of some sort. Do you permit it?

Comment: Absolutely! By all means.

Comment: Oh, all right. Thank you.

Comment: I suspected, the derivative of the function LHS-RHS is greater than zero throughout the range. You can try and prove this.

Comment: I have but it by no means obvious. One just ends up with another inequality requiring its own separate proof that it remains positive on the interval of interest.

Comment: That's true. This question is more difficult than I thought initially. I shall try to return with an answer.

Comment: Yeah no I'm stumped lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x$ by $\frac \pi 2 - x$ (as in Jack D'Aurizio's answer), so that
we have to show that
$$
 \tan x  < \frac{x (\pi - 2x)}{\pi - 4x} \quad \text{for } 0 < x < \frac \pi 4 \, .
$$
Denote the right-hand side with $g(x)$. The idea is to use the fact
that $\tan$ is a solution of the differential equation (initial
value problem)
$$
  y' = 1 + y^2 \, , \quad y(0) = 0
$$
and to show that $g$ satisfies a corresponding differential *inequality.*

We have $g(0) = 0$, and a straight-forward calculation gives
$$
 g'(x) - g(x)^2 - 1 = \frac{x(\pi - 2x)(2x^2 - \pi x + 4)}{(\pi - 4x)^2} > 0
$$
for  $0 < x < \frac \pi 4$.

It follows that
$$
 \arctan(g(x)) = \int_0^x  \frac{g'(t)}{1 + g(t)^2} \, dt > \int_0^x 1 \, dt = x
$$
and therefore $g(x) > \tan x$.

Comment: That is really clever.

Answer (score 2):

By performing the change of variable $x\mapsto\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$ it is enough to show that

$$\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\cot(x) > -2+\frac{\pi}{2x} $$
holds for any $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, or that over the same interval
$$\frac{\tan(x)}{x}<\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{\frac{\pi}{2}-2x} \tag{1} $$
holds. That can be done by comparing the coefficients in the Taylor series of the RHS and LHS at the origin. By considering the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the cosine function,
$$ \frac{\tan(x)}{x}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{2(4^k-1)\zeta(2k)}{\pi^{2k}}\,x^{2k-2} \tag{2}$$
while
$$\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{\frac{\pi}{2}-2x}=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{\pi^n}\,x^n \tag{3}$$
hence it is enough to show that
$$ \frac{2^{4k-3}}{\pi^{2k-1}}x^{2k-1}+\frac{2^{4k-1}}{\pi^{2k}}x^{2k}\geq \frac{2(4^{k+1}-1)\zeta(2k+2)}{\pi^{2k+2}}x^{2k}\tag{4} $$
holds for every $k\geq 1$ and every $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, but that is straightforward.

Comment: Since $\sin x \leq x$, from (1), it is sufficient that $\cos x>\dfrac{\pi/2-2x}{\pi/2-x}$, which is equivalent to $\sin y>2-\dfrac{\pi}{2y}$ in the original interval $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$. This weaker inequality appears to be true.

Comment: Yes, your 2 last lines are enough... I have plotted the initial functions $y=x \tan x$ and $y= \frac{4x - \pi}{\pi - 2x}$ and been surprised that we are very far from a close approximation: the gap is alway $>0.78...$ !

Comment: @JeanMarie: indeed I used an atom bomb (the method employed in some proofs of Huygens-type inequalities) to crack a small nut, since the given inequality is not very tight. However, I hope the outlined approach can be useful for the OP and interested readers.

Comment: For instance, $$ x \tan x > \frac{x^2}{1-\frac{x^2}{3}},\qquad x\tan x > \frac{x-\frac{\pi}{6}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^2}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x} $$ are tighter (they come from Padé approximants) and can be proved through the same approach.

Comment: Yes, using the beginning of a continued fraction...

Answer (score 2):

For $0<x\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$ our inequality is obviously true.

Let $\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $t=\tan{x}$.

Hence, $t>1$ and we need to prove that
$$(\pi-2x)x\tan{x}>4x-\pi$$ or
$$2x^2\tan{x}+(4-\pi\tan{x})x-\pi>0$$ or
$$x<\frac{-4+\pi\tan{x}+\sqrt{16+\pi^2\tan^2x}}{4\tan{x}}$$
or $f(x)>0$, where
$$f(x)=\frac{-4+\pi\tan{x}+\sqrt{16+\pi^2\tan^2x}}{4\tan{x}}-x.$$
We see that
$$f'(x)=\frac{\cos^2x\sqrt{16+\pi^2\tan^2x}-4}{\sin^2x\sqrt{16+\pi^2\tan^2x}}.$$
We'll prove that $f'(x)<0$ for all $\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Indeed, it's enough to prove that
$$\cos^2x\sqrt{16+\pi^2\tan^2x}<4$$ or
$$\sqrt{16+\pi^2t^2}<4(1+t^2)$$ or
$$16t^4+(32-\pi^2)t^2>0,$$
which is obvious.

Id est, $$f(x)>\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}^+}f(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}=0$$
and we are done!